# CSS Background Image and Padding

Tags: css, padding

I want to set a background image in a div class, and want to add some text on the image, with 5px padding but my text is overflowing, please see my css and demo here http://jsfiddle.net/LcQzG/ and help me with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should set a width and add

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/LcQzG/6/

Comment: Thanks, but as you see there is no padding in bottom, any idea why padding in bottom doesnt work?

Comment: because , content is very long for box.

Comment: I didn't try, but you can look at this for the text-overflow : http://chetzit.com/blog/css/9.html

Answer (score 1):

Either make the background image higher, make the text smaller, make the box wider or add this to add a scroll bar:

```
overflow: auto;
```

or to hide the overflowing text:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks but if you see http://jsfiddle.net/LcQzG/, i have already tried with overflow:hidden, but dont know why it doesnt work.

Comment: You have to set a height for the box if you wan to use overflow.

Comment: The height is extended by the padding * 2. You should decrese the height by two times the padding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width on the containing div. The width would be the width of the image - 10px (the sum of the left and right padding).

Comment: Whoops, didn't see that Eray Alakese already said to add a width.